# Achieve incremental values for a month based on value in another column and date

Tags: sql, teradata, increment, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I’m having a scenario where I have to increment the numbers in a month.
Condition 1 : If the value in col2 is greater than 0 then expected output is 0.
Condition 2: If value in col1 is 0 then expected output should be 999.
Condition 3: If the value in col2 is 0 then increment the numbers from 1.

Note: If either condition 1 or condition 2 is satisfied while incrementing then we must increment again from 1.

```
Id    Date     Col1   col2.  Expected Output
101   01/01     28      1.       0
101   01/02     43      0        1
101   01/03     46      0.       2
101   01/04     0       0.      999
101   01/05     56      0        1
101   01/06     95      5.       0
101   01/07     0       0.      999
101   01/08     65      0.       1
101   01/09     1       0.       2
101   01/10     2       0.       3
```

Please suggest how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

A cumulative count plus Teradata's RESET WHEN option:

```
-- similar to ROW_NUMBER, but counts only zeros
case
  when col1 = 0 then 999
  else count(case  when col2 > 0 or col1 = 0 then NULL else 1 end)
       over (partition by id
             order by date_
             reset when col2 > 0 or col1 = 0
             rows unbounded preceding)
end
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for the response. It seemed to work but the row number is repeating from number 2 instead of 1. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Sorry, ROW_NUMBER was not correct. Modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response but with the count I’m not able to increment the numbers if the value in col3 is 0 for next 4 days.

Comment: This returns exactly what you want. Can you provide your actual query?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, sorry for not being clear earlier and thank you for the response. I updated   my scenario again in the question. Please check and let me know if this possible.

Comment: This is a totaly different question now. It's much easier to solve when you explain your logic in detail, now it's just another guess based on the expected result.